# Any advice on my thesis for a history paper on the issue of illegal immigration in 20th Century America?

Tags: united-states, immigration

Here is the prompt:

> **Prompt:** In Impossible Subjects, historian Mae Ngai provides a sociolegal history of illegal immigration to the United States in the
>   twentieth century. Law and policy are the centers of her book, and she
>   examines them at three levels: “in the legislative and political
>   discourses of restriction; in judicial decisions that sought to square
>   competing demands of sovereignty and individual rights; and in the
>   practical articulation of the law, the everyday meanings and
>   consequences of law that are provided by the bureaucratic state’s
>   interactions with migrants and with other social actors (p. 12).”
>
> By using Impossible Subjects, examine how these three levels of law and policy shaped the issues of illegal immigration in
>   twentieth-century America.
>
> You are strictly prohibited from using any other external sources. Violators will be penalized. You can use factual information provided
>   by the lectures, but I would discourage you from relying on them. The
>   point of the assignment is that you should fill the paper with your
>   analysis of information and arguments provided in the Ngai’s book.

Here is my introduction:

The notion of illegal aliens emerged in America under the Immigration Act of 1924. Previously, immigrants who were in America unofficially were given no title, and therefore were indistinguishable from the immigrants who had gone through the processes necessary for citizenship.The advent of this new class of people, illegal immigrants, ushered in a new subject for political and social discourse and judicial decisions, and created and empowered government entities to enforce any new legislation. In twentieth-century America, the political legislation and discourse legitimized racist ideas about illegal immigrants, the judicial decisions reinforced the perceived validity of these racist ideas, and ground level enforcement and social debate dispersed these ideas among the population.

-I know "racist ideas" may not be specific enough so if anyone has any advice regarding that specifically that would be awesome.

Comment: You'll need to look at Ngai's book to see what she says about those three levels. If there are specific words in that quote from p. 12 you don't understand, look them up first.

Comment: I feel like while it's historical policy, this belongs more in politics SE.

Comment: It would be difficult for anyone here to assist, since the entirety of your paper must be based on the one cited work.

Comment: The specific forms of "racist ideas" that Ngai discusses are eugenics and nativism.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question.